# Partition of Real Numberss

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $\Pi$ be a partition of $\mathbb{R}$.
It is possible that $\forall x \in \Pi$ $|x| = |\Pi|$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is a standard result that $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$ have the same cardinality; in particular, there exists a bijection $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$. Then
$$
\Pi = \big\{ f^{-1}(\Bbb R\times\{y\})\colon y\in\Bbb R\big\}
$$
is a partition of $\Bbb R$ such that $\#\Pi=\#\Bbb R$ and $\#x=\#\Bbb R$ for all $x\in\Pi$.

Comment: what $\#$ means?

Comment: $\#S$ and $|S|$ are two notations for the cardinality of a set.